# Missing kotlin.js.map file compiling Kotlin to javascript to gradle

Tags: gradle, kotlin

I compile Kotlin to JS and it works quite well, but the Browser always shows the error:

in the console log.

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>   http://localhost:63342/engineEmi/web/js/kotlin.js.map

This is my **build.gradle** file:

```
group 'org.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
apply plugin: 'kotlin2js'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-js:$kotlin_version"
}

task assembleWeb(type: Sync) {
    configurations.compile.each { File file ->
        from(zipTree(file.absolutePath), {
            includeEmptyDirs = false
            include { fileTreeElement ->
                def path = fileTreeElement.path
                path.endsWith(".js") && (path.startsWith("META-INF/resources/") ||
                        !path.startsWith("META-INF/"))
            }
        })
    }
    compileKotlin2Js {
        kotlinOptions.outputFile = "${projectDir}/web/output.js"
        kotlinOptions.moduleKind = "plain"
        kotlinOptions.sourceMap = true
        kotlinOptions.sourceMapEmbedSources = "always"


    }

    from compileKotlin2Js.destinationDir
    into "${projectDir}/web/js"
    dependsOn classes
}

task copyHTMLFolder(type: Copy) {
    dependsOn assembleWeb
    from file("src/html/")
    into file("${projectDir}/web/")
}

task openUrlInBrowser {
    dependsOn copyHTMLFolder
    doLast {
        java.awt.Desktop.desktop.browse "http://localhost:63342/engineEmi/web/index.html".toURI()
    }
}

assemble.dependsOn assembleWeb

sourceSets {
    main.kotlin.srcDirs += 'src/'
    main.java.srcDirs += 'src/'
}
```

How can I let gradle generate the kotlin.ja.map file?

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

Silly me. The file WAS created, but it was not copied from META-INF because only .js files where copied.

Here is the working implementation of the assembleWeb Task (see the Conditional with path.endsWith

```
task assembleWeb(type: Sync) {
    configurations.compile.each { File file ->
        from(zipTree(file.absolutePath), {
            includeEmptyDirs = false
            include { fileTreeElement ->
                def path = fileTreeElement.path
                (path.endsWith(".js") || path.endsWith(".map")) && (path.startsWith("META-INF/resources/") || !path.startsWith("META-INF/"))
            }
        })
    }
    compileKotlin2Js {
        kotlinOptions.outputFile = "${projectDir}/web/output.js"
        kotlinOptions.moduleKind = "plain"
        kotlinOptions.sourceMap = true
        kotlinOptions.sourceMapEmbedSources = "always"


    }

    from compileKotlin2Js.destinationDir
    into "${projectDir}/web/js"
    dependsOn classes
}
```